# Create a Google Sheets chart with multiple data ranges with separate key columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have this data:

```
 X1      Y1      X2     Y2
  1      20       1     25
  2      20       3     42
  3      20       6     50
  5      25       8     50
 10      30      10     50
```

I want to create a graph that overlays two lines, one with X1 as X axis, Y1 as Y axis, and one with X2 and Y2.

Values with the same X are meant to line up, so at 3 on the X axis, there's supposed to be 20 for Y1 and 42 for Y2. Just adding two data ranges to the graph won't do that.

My current plan is to create two intermediate data ranges that are basically exploded, so it interpolates the data in each range so there's a value for every single X (see [my question here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63165/how-to-interpolate-data-in-a-range-in-google-sheets)). But that approach doesn't sound very smart, there must be a better way.

[image: Note how 20 and 42 line up at 3 along the horizontal axis even though they are in different rows in the data range]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Please try with layout as shown. Select `A1:C11` (or to suit), insert Line chart with Use row 1 as headers and Use column A as labels:

[image: WA63174 example]

Comment: I guess I should feel embarrassed for not coming up with that myself. Thanks pnuts!

Comment: I was having trouble getting this to work. Maybe I should feel embarrassed too.

Comment: Yeah i did get it to work eventually, though it does seem to ignore the 2nd series depending on your exact workflow.

Comment: What kind of chart is this?

Comment: I figured it out: "Line Chart" in Google Sheets.

Answer (score 2):

You can bring you data in `A:C` to the format

```
X       
1   20  Y1
2   20  Y1
3   20  Y1
5   25  Y1
10  30  Y1
1   25  Y2
3   42  Y2
6   50  Y2
8   50  Y2
10  50  Y2
```

and then use

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select A, avg(B) where A is not null group by A pivot C")
```

to generate

```
X   Y1  Y2
1   20  25
2   20  
3   20  42
5   25  
6       50
8       50
10  30  50
```

ready to plot.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to duplicate the `X` values.

- Just put the `Y2` values in a different column from `Y1`.
- Create a chart from `A1:C5`.
- Edit the chart and select line chart if necessary.

Comment: X values are not the same for Y1 data and Y2 data. Does your approach account for this?