# How do you interpolate data in a horizontal range that's non-linear?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-charts, google-sheets-dates

I've been told what I'm hoping to do is called 'spline interpolation'.

I've imported monthly youtube channel viewership figures from google API. And I've layed out the dates and views in a horizontal range. On the right I want to be able to pick a date and show a rough viewership figure that's close to the actual viewership figure, so interpolating as if it were on a curved line of best fit with multiple peaks and trophs.

The reason is to create a youtube channel directory with monthly actual viewership figure and % monthly difference on a curved line of best fit since the channels beginning.

Here's the google spreadsheet example anyone can edit:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzC04y5DXJG9334a9za_vgTu7NI1aIh0C87IXsKJt3Q/edit?usp=sharing

And I need it to work with blank/unknown cells. So using a formula that doesn't treat empty cells as an error, or fills them in based on the average of known figures to both sides in a series.

This is the closest answer I've found so far, but I can't get the formula/code to work:

[How to interpolate data in a range in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/63165/how-to-interpolate-data-in-a-range-in-google-sheets)

Comment: Welcome to WebApps. Would you please  explain the outcome that you are trying to achieve and the specific programming problem that you are facing. Your question, as it stands, assumes a level of knowledge about you and your spreadsheet.

Comment: Heya @Tedinoz, thanks for replying, I've updated the post and google doc to try to be more clear. If you have any more questions let me know.

Comment: Is it your intention to create 85+/- separate charts?

Comment: I don't desire to see/create graphs, just use a formula/code to if possible analyse the data and know what a non-linear line of best fit would say was the latest month viewership figure. So a formula drawing from all the numbers in the row and spitting out a number in the final cell under the latest month.

Answer (score 0):

You are analysing data for 'line of best fit' where there are missing elements in the data range. [How to interpolate data in a range in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/63215/196152) has provided a custom function with which to identify the missing elements.

The following formula attempts to provide a method by which the interpolated data can be calculated.

The formula is a combination of of `vlookup` to return actual data values and the custom function `myInterpolation()` to return values for missing data elements.

The data is based on views for channel "Patrik Baboumian"

`'=iferror(vlookup(C3,$A$3:$B$26,2,false),round(myInterpolation($A$3:$A$26, $B$3:$B$26, C3),0))`

---

**Actual Data and Interpolated data**

[image: Actual Data and Interpolated data]

Comment: Looks like a great start. I could really do with the line of best fit being curved though i.e. with double, triple or more exponential smoothing. That way the final figure wouldn't be the same as the actual number.

If possible could you also show your work in a google doc so I can see which cells the formula is drawing from and going to.

Comment: [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xzhgi_25NcncrU0rMXt0p-Cdk-8f8saMjan7GPsgocY/edit?usp=sharing); check the sheet "Interpolate". "I could really do with the line of best fit being curved though". To be honest, I was out of my league doing this much. This kind of maths is not my thing-but it is v. interesting. But I'm learning ;-) [Explain double and triple smoothing methods in plain english](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/138791)

Comment: Also [Holt-Winters Forecasting for Dummies (or Developers) - Part I, II and III](https://grisha.org/blog/2016/01/29/triple-exponential-smoothing-forecasting/). Always wanted to learn Python... !

Comment: I've managed to do linear regression: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZzC04y5DXJG9334a9za_vgTu7NI1aIh0C87IXsKJt3Q/edit?usp=sharing

But I've been told what I'm hoping to do is called 'spline interpolation'. So as to be able to get viewership figures on a curved line of best fit with multiple peaks and trophs.

Comment: Just found an add-on that offers spline interpolation. https://sites.google.com/view/interpolation/home

Comment: Unfortunately the add-on doesn't do any explaining how it's supposed to work, just says type =Interpo(x, xRange, yRange) and when the cells entered comes back "only one item in iRangeX" it doesn't explain what that means. And on the website it just says "Coming soon: video tutorial, cerchara, cerchamx and cerchamy"